# How I can get navigation bar on Page under NavigationPane

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How I can get a Navigationbar kind of thing like in settings application (attached screen shot) on a page without making it a sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it's solution on Blackberry forum on given link below.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/How-I-can-get-navigation-bar-on-Page-under-NavigationPane/m-p/2117057#M12495